# Not sure what data structure to use

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm currently trying to work with vectors / deques of structures.  Simple example of the structure...

```
struct job {
    int id;
    int time;
}
```

I want to be able to search through the structure to find the job that matches the time, remove it from the structure and continue to check for other ids in that structure.  Sample code...

```
<vector> jobs;
<deque> started;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < jobs.size(); i++)
{
    if (jobs.at(i).time == time)
    {
        started.push_back(jobs.at(i));
        jobs.erase(jobs.begin() + i);
        i--;
    }
} 

time++;
```

This works how I want it to but it also seems very hacky since I'm adjusting the index whenever I delete and I think it's simply because I'm not as knowledgeable as should be with data structures.  Anyone able to give me some advice?

NOTE - I don't think this is a duplicate to what this post has been tagged to as I'm not looking to do something efficiently with what I already have.  To me, it seems efficient enough considering I'm reducing the size of the deque each time I get what I need from it.  What I was hoping for, is some advice on figuring out what is the best data structure for what I'm attempting to do with deques, which are likely not meant to be handled as I'm handling them.

I could also be wrong and my usage is fine but just seems off to me to.

Comment: ok thanks Jon!  I'll give that a look

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient way of erasing/deleting multiple std::vector elements while retaining original order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115279/most-efficient-way-of-erasing-deleting-multiple-stdvector-elements-while-retai)

Comment: Hi Drop.  I'm looking more for a better structure to handle what I'm doing currently with the deque.  I also don't need what the order is because the structures have the information I need for order.  Seems like a good post though so I'll be reading through it

Comment: You may want to look into a `std::multiset` which has an inherent sorting (though you need to tell it that `job`s are sorted by `job.time`). Erasing elements should also be pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I always knew that [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qH6sSOr-yk8) would come in handy! The message here is "know your STL algorithms". With that, let me introduce you to `std::stable_partition`.

One thing you can do is use just one single vector, as follows:

```
using namespace std;
vector<job> jobs;
// fill the vector with jobs
auto startedJobsIter = stable_partition(begin(jobs), end(jobs), 
    [=time](job const &_job) { return _job.time == time; });
```

Now, everything between `begin(jobs)` and `startedJobsIter` satisfy the condition, while everything from `startedJobsIter` and `end(jobs)` does not.

**Edit**

If you don't care about the relative ordering of the items, then you could just use `std::partition`, which could be even more performant, because it would not preserve the relative ordering of the elements in the original vector, but will still divide it into the two parts.

**Edit 2**

Here's an adaptation for older C++ standards:

```
struct job_time_predicate {
public:
    job_time_predicate(int time) : time_(time) { }
    bool operator()(job const &the_job) { return the_job.time == time_; }
private:
    int time_;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int time = 10;
    vector<job> jobs;
    // fill that vector
    vector<job>::iterator startedJobsIter = 
        stable_partition(jobs.begin(), jobs.end(), job_time_predicate(time));
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you Nasser!  I will have a look at your talk as well!  Out of curiosity, is this all C++11?   I don't think this will work for me.  I'm asking since I noticed the thumbnail to the youtube video shows C++11

Comment: I did use C++11 stuff here, but neither `stable_partition` nor `partition` are C++11, and you can adapt this solution to older C++ standards.

Comment: Huh. I'm surprised to see `std::stable_partition` used for this. I expected `std::remove_if`

Comment: @MooingDuck that would work as well. Do you see any disadvantage of using `stable_partition` or `partition` to using `remove_if`? Feel free to submit an edit if you want.

Comment: @Nasser: Honestly, I've just spent the last 10 minutes trying to figure out if there's any difference between them.  Then I gave up and did an SO Search: "Both remove_if and partition put the "good" elements first. partition puts the "bad" elements after that, whereas remove_if does not specify what comes after it -- it might be the bad elements, but it might also be copies of any (either good or bad) elements."  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521352/difference-between-partition-and-remove-functions-in-c I hadn't realized how similar they are.